# Minimalmodbus function code 0x46 and sub function 06

Tags: python-3.x, modbus, minimalmodbus

I am communicating with an irradiation sensor using minimalmodbus in Python 3.x. I can stablish a communication and read the registers of the sensor. The Baudrate of the sensor is 9600 but I want to change it to 38400.

The datasheet of the sensor says that it can be done by using the function code 0x46 and the subfunction 06.

[datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciybC.png)

I've found that minimalmodbus only uses function codes 1,2,3,4,5,6,15 and 16, and I haven't found any possibility to use sub function.

Is there any option for me to change the baudrate or should I change minimalmodbus for another library as pyModbus?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Minimalmodbus documentation, you can "extend" it to handle more function codes by using the _performCommand() function.  The documentation says that it will take care of the CRC generation.

Link: https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.io/en/master/develop.html#extending-minimalmodbus

I did a quick search and it looks like you are using a Tamb485 sensor.  Based on that documentation, To set the BAUD rate to 38400 and the parity/stop bits (both are set at the same time) to 8E1 on a device you would do:

```
_performCommand(0x46, '0x05,0x04,0x02')

0x46 - function code

0x05 - sub function code
0x04 - baud rate 38400
0x02 - parity/stop bits 8E1
```

Comment: I just used _performCommand(70, '\x06\x04\x00') and it worked fine! Thanks

Comment: Great, I see that I didn't look close enough at that function to see that the address was implied and the function code was a parameter, I'll update my answer.   Glad it pointed you in the right direction anyway.